# mysql: ERROR: Option 'debug=d:t:o,/var/log/list.log' used, but is disabled

Tags: mysql, debugging, logging

In my app I get

```
mysql: ERROR: Option 'debug=d:t:o,/var/log/list.log' used, but is disabled
```

how can I enable --debug in mysql?
If possible without changing my.conf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution

Instead of

```
mysql --debug .......
```

I do

```
mysql ............... <<EOF 2>>/var/log/list.log
```

its saving errors and warnings to the file